# How can I fix the missing /NST/AutoNeoGrub0.mbr on Windows 8.1?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8, easybcd

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 onto my Windows 8.1 UEFI SONY VAIO laptop. I installed ubuntu by clicking 'something else' in the installation window. I then made 3 partitions: `/boot` , `/` and a `swap` partition. It installed without any problem and when I restarted grub 2 page came on.

But when I went into the Windows 8.1 and restarted again, to come out to go into the Ubuntu, there was no grub 2 page. Even I used EasyBCD to add the OS to the boot list. When I boot, it comes up with the boot manager, showing Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu.

I can boot into 8 perfectly fine, but when I try to boot into Ubuntu it comes up with a `0xc000007c` error saying that `/NST/AutoNeoGrub0.mbr is missing or corrupt`.

Apart from EasyBCD, is there another way to solve this problem? Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance for your care.